# What are the implications of using mods in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I'd like to install the Redpower mod, but every time that this comes to my mind I try to imagine the situation after I installed it and I feel like minecraft wouldn't be pure anymore, full or risks and bugs or will simply ruin my old save games or that my games started and saved with the mod will be not be compatible with a vanilla version of minecraft.

I'm not gonna ask you if I should mod minecraft or not. I just want to ask:

- What happens internally to the minecraft application?
- What happens with the old saved games?
- What is the compatibility of modded saved games versus a vanilla minecraft installation?
- What else should I be aware of?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- What happens internally to the minecraft application?

Currently, the way Minecraft Mods work is by modifying the `minecraft.jar` that contains all the game code. This changes the code to allow extra features such as Single Player Commands or Zepplin Mod.

- What happens with the old saved games?

Nothing will happen to your old saved games.

- What is the compatibility of modded saved games versus a vanilla minecraft game?

A modded save game will work fine in vanilla minecraft. However, if you use a mod that adds new blocks (such as a nuke block) having those blocks in your inventory or placed in your world will cause them to not appear or worse.

- What else should I be aware of?

Do note that sometimes mods may not be compatible. This is usually because they modify the same source files, which means that when you install one, and then the other, the other will overwrite the first one, meaning that first mod will not be able to use that source file.

Also, sometimes when I install minecraft mods, minecraft does not start up. If that happens, I use the following command to start minecraft.

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -cp "%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\*" -Djava.library.path="%APPDATA%\.minecraft\bin\natives" net.minecraft.client.Minecraf
```

(it goes in the run box which you open by pressing <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>)

Comment: This could defintitly be updated to a more modern version since we don't modify the jar most of the time anymore we use mod loaders which technically do modify the Minecraft.jar but only once, the rest of the mods load and hook into things.. Only 'Core mods' change the minecraft jar, which the most common are mod loaders, though a few others like x-ray and so on exist.

Comment: @Codingale absolutely true, however I haven't played Minecraft in years. Hopefully someone else can fix this